# High latency for bind9 over wireguard

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, bind, wireguard

I have a DNS home server running with bind9. To keep using my server outside my local network, I configured a VPN with wireguard.
With this command : `time wget -O/dev/null https://debian.org`, here are the latencies of the same request in two different network environments

```
Local network                    ---> 0,647s
Outside network (over wireguard) ---> 11,007s
```

If i make the test with an IP Address : `time wget -O/dev/null https://128.31.0.62 --no-check-certificate` :

```
Local network                    ---> 0,459s
Outside network (over wireguard) ---> 0,738s
```

I don't understand why the name resolution over wireguard is so slow.

#### Edit

As @mtak wrote in response, to test if the problem comes from the name resolution, we used the following commands : `time dig debian.org @1.2.3.4` where 1.2.3.4 is the IP of the bind server.

```
Local network   ---> 0,058s
Outside network ---> 0,036s
```

So if the problem isn't name resolution, what is it ?

Comment: While I understand that your results lead you to think that resolving is the problem, it would be good to actually include the time it takes to do a request on your bind server. Add `time dig debian.org @1.2.3.4` where 1.2.3.4 is the IP of your bind server.

Comment: With `time dig debian.org @192.168.1.2` (local network) ---> 0,058s | And `time dig debian.org @192.168.2.1` (over wireguard) ---> 0,036s. So if it's not the name resolution, what could it be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that was the **resolv.conf** file. The DNS server of the local network was above that of the external network. And as it says in the resolv.conf manual :

```
If there are multiple servers, the resolver library queries them in the order listed.
```

So It was the first DNS server query time that was causing the latency.